# SceneKit changing the scattering function

Tags: swift, scenekit

I've loaded 4 `.obj` files that represent an anatomical heart model using this method:

```
private func nodeForURL(url: NSURL) -> SCNNode
{
    let asset = MDLAsset(URL: url)
    let object = asset.objectAtIndex(0)
    let node = SCNNode(MDLObject: object)

    return node
}
```

The 4 `.obj` files each contain a reference to a corresponding `.mtl` file, so in addition to the geometry, they get the correct texture bump map.

The issue is that the default lighting isn't particularly realistic. How do you change to use the `MDLPhysicallyPlausibleScatteringFunction`? Are there other scattering functions to try?

Answer (score 1):

Model I/O was designed as an interexchange format and not all that it can represent is supported by SceneKit. If SceneKit APIs don't expose what you're looking for, there's little to no chance that using an intermediate Model I/O object will help.